# ggplot/plot in Shiny not working

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I have a dataframe that has no NA values. I am trying to make a ggplot or a simple plot in Shiny but I am not able to achieve any of them. The first code snippet is attempt to make ggplot while second snippet is an attempt for a simple plot.

The code below produces "need finite 'xlim' values as output in plot area. In the code below, colspa and rgbchoice are 2 selectInput vaiables from ui.R.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        col.str <- paste0(input$colspa, ".", input$rgbchoice, ".avg")
        q <- plot(art.data$year, art.data[[col.str]])
        plot(q)
    })
})
```

Below is snap of a part of the dataframe.

[dataframe snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WO0u.jpg)

Comment: I'm confused about what you are doing with col.str. Your y variable is a character?  Also in the second example `art.data[[col.str]]` ... what are you trying to do there? col.str is the name of a character vector that is the same length as input (whatever inut is). How does that relate to art.data? Please give clear example with a small amount of data and no link, so that someone could copy and paste your code.

Comment: @Elin I have edited the question. Hope it makes things clearer.

Comment: You need to make a minimal complete verifiable example. Your snap, by the way, does not show any columns with two "." characters.  But do not use a snap provide a small data set with 4-5 rows and the three variables.